# printing values of a struct - getting error expected one of `,` or `}`

Tags: rust

This is an example from a tutorial that I am following:

```
fn main() {
    let name_length = NameLength::new("John");
    name_length.print();
}

struct NameLength {
    name: String,
    length: usize,
}

impl NameLength {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
        NameLength {
            name.to_string(),
            length: name.len(),
        }
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        println!(
            "The name '{}' is '{}' characters long",
            self.name, self.length
        );
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
error: expected one of `,` or `}`, found `.`
  --> src/main.rs:14:17
   |
13 |         NameLength {
   |         ---------- while parsing this struct
14 |             name.to_string(),
   |                 ^ expected one of `,` or `}`

error[E0063]: missing field `name` in initializer of `NameLength`
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         NameLength {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ missing `name`
```

I tried creating the constructor in the following way:

```
fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
    NameLength {  
        name,          
        length: name.len(),
    }
}
```

I still get an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
14 |             name,
   |             ^^^^
   |             |
   |             expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&str`
   |             help: try using a conversion method: `name: name.to_string()`
```

Comment: i don't know Rust, but is it expecting the property name? `name: name.to_String()`

Comment: `NameLength { name, ... }` is just a shorthand when the property name matches the variable name: `NameLength { name: name, ... }` but since you're using more than just the variable name, you need to spell it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new` method needs to be

```
fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
    NameLength {
        name: name.to_string(),          
        length: name.len(),
    }
}
```

In your first try, with just `name.to_string()`, Rust doesn't know which struct member you're trying to set that to. In the second try, just `name`, `name` is a `&str`, not a `String`, because you got rid of the `.to_string()` call.